# How to correctly store sensitive data in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, cryptography, pgcrypto

So I'm making a web app where users will upload sensitive data (private finances records), so I want to encrypt one column in one table that holds the value.

The table is "Movement" and the column name is "value".

I've done some research and find out I can use pgcrypto extension.

If I understood correctly, I need to use a public key approach (instead of symmetric) because I want only for the users that created the data to be able to access it.

So, I need to generate a public a private key, using a password, and then encrypt the file using the public key.

Then I can decrypt it using the private key and the password. So I have a couple of questions:

1. Where should the the public/private key and the password stored?
2. Every user needs their own public/private key and password?
3. At which point do this keys/password need to be created? During user creation?

Comment: Seems unworkable.  If I can trust you with my private key and password, why can't I just trust you with my plain data in the first place?  To get meaningfully enhanced security using private/public keys, the decryption has to be done on the user's hardware, not on your hardware.

Comment: @jjanes Makes sense but then, if my user stores his private key/pass in his PC nº1. Then he logs in in PC nº2, how can he decrypt the data if PC nº2 doesn't have the private key?

Comment: The way protonmail does it is they store the encrypted private key on their server, and then send that to anyone who can prove they know the password (but in a way that doesn't involve their server seeing the password).  Then the user decrypts the private key locally and uses it locally.  Of course you have to trust that their software does what it says it does.